# Manipulating python function outputs with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, scipy

From stats.scipy, I've applied the coefficent of variation test to each numeric column in my dataframe and I want to screen the output so that it only shows columns that have values above 0 and that aren't missing. Here's my code:

```
x = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).apply(stats.variation)*100

for i in x:
    if i != 'NaN' and i != 0:
        print i
```

It still returns NaN and values of 0. How can I fix this? Also, how can I format it so that the loop returns the name of the variable as well as the numeric value?

EDIT:
Here's the output of the function which I stored in x:

```
 var_1               NaN
 var_2               3.809518
 var_5               7.031835
 var_10              20.190090
 var_20              21.217053
 var_30              20.806000
```

I want to format the output so that var_1 won't be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) for check `NaN`, then check `0` ang return where all `True` by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html). Last use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.notnull() & (df != 0)).all()

print (df.loc[:, mask])
```

Sample:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,0],
                   'B':[4,np.nan,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (x)
   A    B  C
0  1  4.0  7
1  0  NaN  8
2  0  6.0  9

print (x.notnull() & (x != 0))
       A      B     C
0   True   True  True
1  False  False  True
2  False   True  True

print ((x.notnull() & (x != 0)).all())
A    False
B    False
C     True
dtype: bool

mask = (x.notnull() & (x != 0)).all()
print (x.loc[:, mask])
   C
0  7
1  8
2  9
```

EDIT:

if `x` is `Series` use:

```
x = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 0, 0, 5, np.nan])
print (x)
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    5.0
5    NaN
dtype: float64

print (x[x.notnull() & (x != 0)])
1    1.0
4    5.0
dtype: float64
```

EDIT1:

```
x = pd.Series([np.nan, 3.809518, 7.031835000000001, 20.190089999999998, 21.217053, 20.806], 
              index=['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_5', 'var_10', 'var_20', 'var_30'])
print (x)
var_1           NaN
var_2      3.809518
var_5      7.031835
var_10    20.190090
var_20    21.217053
var_30    20.806000
dtype: float64

print (x.notnull() & (x != 0))
var_1     False
var_2      True
var_5      True
var_10     True
var_20     True
var_30     True
dtype: bool

print (x[x.notnull() & (x != 0)])
var_2      3.809518
var_5      7.031835
var_10    20.190090
var_20    21.217053
var_30    20.806000
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Tried your code on the function output, and I received an error message: Too many indexers

Comment: what is `x.info()` ?

Comment: x.info() returns an error. type(x) is a pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: I ran that code and then the mask code in your answer, and it just returns an empty dataframe

Comment: Sorry mate, tried the edit code and it didn't work either

Comment: maybe you can add some sample code with desired output